# MultiprocessIterator doesn't work

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocess, chainer

I am using *MultiprocessIterator* from *chainer* to train an NN. The code is [here](https://github.com/cmjdxy/practice-chainer/blob/master/train_mnist.py).

The results are:

```
nproc = 1,  307.65s
nproc = 4,  318.85s
nproc = 8,  302.91s
nproc = 16, 318.18s
```

System info:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-104-generic x86_64)
CPU(s): 16
Model name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2695 v4 @ 2.10GHz
VGA compatible controller: Cirrus Logic GD 5446
```

It seems *MultiprocessIterator* doesn't work. Anyone has a clue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Post the (relevant) code in your question please.

Comment: I tried, but the system said "It looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details" and didn't approve my post. So I use a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from: https://github.com/chainer/chainer/issues/4723

> MultiiprocessIterator just (sometimes) speeds up picking up a batch
>   from Dataset and it does not hasten ANY GPU computation. In most
>   cases, the computational bottleneck is forwarding/backwarding, so it
>   is only natural that MultiiprocessIterator has no effect on the total
>   time.